# Matching algorithm to find an suitable place in a grid

Tags: matching

I'm trying to solve a task from a programming challenge and it should be really easy with a matching algorithm but I'm pretty lost how it should be transfered in a graph.
It should be probably based on max-min-flow or maximum bipartit matching.
Could anybody give me a little hint on how to solve this or how to transfer the input in a graph? Thanks in advance!
[image]

Comment: To represent the problem as a graph, you will need to define the vertices and edges of the graph. The vertices of the graph should represent the elements that you are trying to match, and the edges should represent the connections between the elements.

Comment: After that, you can use a matching algorithm to find a matching that satisfies the constraints of the problem.